# Rakeness Optimization problem

Tags: matlab, optimization, compressive-sensing, convex-optimization

Rakeness optimization problem demonstrate that increases the rakeness between $a$ , $b$  while leaving $b$ random enough.

[image]

where $e$ is the energy of the projection waveforms and $r$ is a randomness-enforcing design parameter.

How to achieve enough randomness in MATLAB?

Comment: You need to give us more information about what you do.